# Books in German on some subjects related to advanced algebra

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Can I get names of German books, published after 1990/2000 on following subjects with some light on recent developments?

- Representation theory of finite groups
- Finite reflection groups / Coxeter groups
- Finite simple groups
- Finite Groups of Lie type

---

(I like to see different books on above subjects, and my Library contains almost English books on above subjects; only one book in German I found was Huppert's Endliche Gruppen. At the same time, I would like to move into some recent progresses on different topics in above subjects, so I mentioned books after 1990/2000.

Apologize if this is not good; but since I don't have any other idea to get books on above subjects in German, so, hope that some Experts from Germa or familiar with German may help!)

---

Since each of these subjects have been independently developed and becoming rich; it is certainly difficult to find a single book devoted to all these subjects with recent developments (1990/2000); ***so this question is not about books of Group Theory as posted in another question on mathstack***. The book of Huppert contains only some part of above four subjects; I am expecting some books fully devoted to only one of these subjects.

I hope this justifies difference between earlier question on german references for *Group Theory* and this question on German references on *Advanced topics in algebra*

Comment: This is not to prevent exercising your gift for languages...but consider that most books published in Germany (by Springer in particular) are either directly written in English, or are translated 2 to 5 years later from German into English. Moreover, this (rather small) latency gives often an improved 2nd edition...

Comment: The same is true for mathematical writings in French (interesting language, as is German).

Comment: It might help if you gave some idea why you are looking for ones in German, Is it simply because this is a more comfortable language for you?